# Mysterious injection error message when starting Play Framework 2.4 application

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, migration, ebean

I'm trying to migrate my app from Play Framework 2.3 to 2.4. The migration documentation state that there is a new routing system that use injection but that the old code from 2.3 should still work, which give us the opportunity to change the router later in the process.

Unfortunately, this is not the case. When I start my application, I get this error. Do I need to add something to say that I want to stay on the old routing system for now? The errors are all related to injection, I don't understand...

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot register class [models.S3BrandFile] in Ebean server]
  while locating play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanModule.bindings(EbeanModule.java:24):
Binding(interface play.db.ebean.EbeanConfig to ProviderConstructionTarget(class play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.db.ebean.EbeanConfig
    for parameter 0 at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:36)
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.class(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:33)
  while locating play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanModule.bindings(EbeanModule.java:23):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions to ConstructionTarget(class play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions
Caused by: Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot register class [models.S3BrandFile] in Ebean server]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:178)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:829)
    at play.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.java:351)
    at play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser.parse(DefaultEbeanConfig.java:105)
    at play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser.get(DefaultEbeanConfig.java:60)
    at play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser.get(DefaultEbeanConfig.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:153)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:150)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:150)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser.parse(DefaultEbeanConfig.java:103)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:71)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:71)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at play.api.Play$.current(Play.scala:71)
    at play.api.Play.current(Play.scala)
    at play.Play.application(Play.java:17)
    at models.S3BrandFile.<clinit>(S3BrandFile.java:25)
    ... 60 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the right answer but it worked for me. After having taken the time to convert the old static router to the new format, I came back at the beginning with the exact same error. So it was clear that this error was not caused by this.

So I search the class for possible "strange" things. I found out that there was a final static variable in my class. As soon as I put the variable in comment, the error changed to another class having the exact same static variable. After 3 or 4 class, it went to another error but at least this one is gone.

This was working without problem in version 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3. I don't understand why it fails right now and there is nothing said about this in the migration documentation.

**Word of advice: Migrating a Play Framework app is a real pain. Be prepared to be frustrated and plan a lot of time and resources for this.**

Comment: Yeah, we're currently stuck on this too. But it was incidental because I scaffolded a new play-scala project using the activator cli tool. And yes, migration/working on a newer version is always a nightmare with Play!. I don't know if Typesafe approves of so many breaking changes and awful documentation just to make more money or if they're actually sucking at documenting their stuff.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they make a lot of money providing "Professionnal Support" for their framework. They don't have any reason to put a decent documentation online since anybody who needs help will come directly to them. We asked for a quote for help migrating and the price was crazy... So we will just go and continue to try by ourselve. For now, it's on hold until we get some free time to try again. Brace yourselves, migration is coming!

Comment: yeah, those possibilities are slightly scary. Would you mind sharing the quoted price for support by Typesafe (privately, if you'd prefer)? We're running 10+ Play! microservices in production and we'd like to re-evaluate our setup so that we're sure we aren't getting into some trouble. :-)
Having said that, we completely do agree that despite the minor hiccups, Play! is a great framework for rapid prototyping and lifecycles. We manage to get our smaller services up and running in a matter of a few days. Its been a boon.

Comment: Yeah sure. For a 6 months "Project success" subscription, it's 10 000 US$. For a "Mentorship Program" of 25 hours that we must use in 3 months or we lose them, it's 6000 US$. It's 240$ the hour... And it took approximately 2 weeks to get these numbers, not counting the multiple sale pitch phone call to propose subscription for years to come. Be aware that it was a 3rd party that is a "typesafe partner" that proposed this. Typesafe kind of ignore me when I said I needed just a couple of hours of help.

Comment: Thanks! And wow, thats worrying. But we aren't considering paid support at this stage. For solving migration problems, we actually stick to a version we're comfortable with: `2.3.8` and I don't yet see the reason to move on to `2.4.x`.

Comment: 1 year later, I am curious if you guys found any real solution or migrated an app from 2.3.8 to 2.4.x? I am stuck with 2.3.8 but have a big performance problem with BoneCP, but I obviously failed to migrate to 2.4.x, with the same error as mentioned by the OP. I tried making variables un-FINAL where possible, but this was not possible everywhere in my huge project. So right now, I hung it up, since I also can't find any further documentation on this issue. Thanks for any info.

Comment: We just migrated to 2.5. It was a brutal and painfull update from 2.3 to 2.4 considering many factor (Dependency injection in one of the worst). Did you try to remove the "static" word in beans? I don't think final is the problem, the problem is "static"